# Prooving an upper bound for $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac {k^2}{N^3} \cos (\frac{k}{N}x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Hello im struggling to proove, that there exsists an constant $C$, so that for every $N \in \mathbb {N}$ and every $ x \in [0,N\pi]$, the following holds:  $$\sum_{k=0}^N \frac {k^2}{N^3} \cos \left(\frac{k}{N}x\right) \leq C\cdot(x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-3})$$

The Approximation is used in the following article:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267676914_CLT_for_Crossings_of_random_trigonometric_Polynomials

Comment: Looks a lot like a Riemann sum. (Which may or may not be relevant)

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider $f(y)=y^2\cos(xy)$. Then
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(y)\,dy = \frac{2x\cos(x)+(x^2-2)\sin(x)}{x^3}\ll 2\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}\right) $$
and the difference between this integral and the associated Riemann sum
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^2 \cos\left(x\frac{k}{N}\right) $$
is bounded by
$\frac{x}{N^2}$
due to the Lipschitz-continuity of $\cos$ and summation/integration by parts.
 It follows that your bound holds as soon as $N\gg|x|$.

Comment: Thank you for your fast Answer. I had the same Idea, but I can´t reproduce the upper bound 
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^2\frac{|x|}{N}\ll\frac{|x|}{N^2}. $$
I think it should be 
$$\frac{|x|}{N} $$ on the right hand side, because ths sum is $O(N)$. Then the upper bound for the difference is a constant only, which is not good enough for my purpose.